# The optimal ranges for the integral homological stability of $\operatorname{GL}_n(F)$'s for a field $F$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology, group-cohomology

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$
$\DeclareMathOperator\co{H}$
$\DeclareMathOperator\ko{K}$
$\DeclareMathOperator\trd{tr-deg}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\ch}{char}$Given a field $F$ and a homological degree $j \geq 1$, define
$$\mathbf{N}(F,j) := \min \left\{N : \co_j(\GL_n(F)) \rightarrow \co_j(\GL_{n+1}(F)) \text{ is an iso. whenever } n \geq N \right\}$$
Here the map is induced by the standard embedding $\GL_n(F) \hookrightarrow \GL_{n+1}(F)$ and the homology is with integer coefficients.

(1) It follows from van der Kallen's general result for rings with finite Bass stable range that we always have $\mathbf{N}(F,j) \leq 2j + 1$.

(2) Sprehn–Wahl show in [Homological stability for classical groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.08742) by reproducing an argument of Quillen that for $F \neq \mathbb{F}_2$ we have $\mathbf{N}(F,j) \leq j + 1$. I believe Quillen's explicit cross-characteristic computations imply if furthermore F is finite that $\mathbf{N}(F,j) \geq \left\lceil\frac{j}{2}\right\rceil$.

(3) It follows from a stable vanishing result of Quillen and the low degree phenomena $\GL_2(\mathbb{F}_2) \cong S_3$, $\GL_4(\mathbb{F}_2) \cong A_8$ that $\mathbf{N}(\mathbb{F}_2,1) = 3$ and $\mathbf{N}(\mathbb{F}_2,2) = 5$. Szymik's computation in [The third Milgram-Priddy class lifts](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.05064) yields $\mathbf{N}(\mathbb{F}_2,3) = 7$.

(4) It follows from [Lahtinen–Sprehn - Modular characteristic classes for representations over finite fields](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.01052) that for every prime $p$ and $m,a \geq 1$, we have $p^m < \mathbf{N}(\mathbb{F}_{p^a}, a(2p^m - 2p^{m-1} - 1))$.

**Edit:** Together with the bounds in Randal-Williams's answer below, we get $\mathbf{N}(\mathbb{F}_{p}, 2p - 3) = p+1$ for every prime $p$.

(5) It follows from Theorem 4.25 in [Nesterenko–Suslin, Homology of the full linear group over a local ring, and Milnor's K-theory](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/IM1990v034n01ABEH000610/pdf?casa_token=snSooFx7RJAAAAAA:CQu6zmYfmwBXNX4hIkF1eUpYzzLEqtozL_UdE37CSbcPJjviWAEEoLZgcPoF_ajIoCB2-FZnDGPYcLaim4M) that for infinite $F$ we have $\mathbf{N}(F,j) \leq j$. Moreover there is an exact sequence
$$\co_j(\GL_{j-1}(F)) \rightarrow \co_j(\GL_{j}(F)) \rightarrow \ko_j^M(F) \rightarrow 0$$
where $\ko_{\star}^M$ is Milnor K-theory. Thus $\ko_j^M(F) \neq 0$ implies $\mathbf{N}(F,j) = j$.

(6) Springer shows in [A remark on the Milnor ring](https://doi.org/10.1016/1385-7258(72)90001-7) that for uncountable $F$ and $j \geq 2$, the group $\ko_j^M(F)$ is uncountable, and hence by (5) we have $\mathbf{N}(F,j) = j$.

(6') In fact Springer shows the following: let $F_0$ be the prime subfield of $F$ and set
$$\delta(F) = \begin{cases} \trd(F/F_0) & \text{if $\ch(F) >0$,}
\\
\trd(F/F_0) + 1 & \text{if $\ch(F) = 0$.}
\end{cases}$$
where $\trd$ denotes the transcendence degree. Then for every $2 \leq j \leq \delta(F)$ we have $\ko_j^M(F) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}\neq 0$, and hence $\mathbf{N}(F,j) = j$ by (5).

(7) Bass–Tate show in [The Milnor ring of a global field](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0073733) that for a number field $F$ that embeds in $\mathbb{R}$ and $j \geq 3$, we have $\ko_j^M(F) \neq 0$ and hence $\mathbf{N}(F,j) = j$ by (5).

(8) Friedlander shows in [Homological stability for classical groups over finite fields](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0080010) (Theorem 3) that for every prime $p$, we have $\mathbf{N}(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p},j) \leq \left\lceil\frac{j+1}{2}\right\rceil$.

(9) It follows from Theorem 2 in [Kroll - The cohomology of the finite general linear group](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(88)90024-2) that for every prime $p$ and even $j$, we have $\mathbf{N}(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p},j) \geq j/2$. Together with (8), here $\mathbf{N}(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p},j)$ must be either $j/2$ or $j/2 + 1$.

(10) A result of Galatius–Kupers–Randal-Williams in [$E_\infty$-cells and general linear groups of infinite fields](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.05620v2) (Corollary 9.16) implies that $\mathbf{N}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}},j) \leq \left\lceil\frac{3j + 1}{4}\right\rceil$.

(11, added after skupers comment): It follows from [Borel–Yang, The rank conjecture for number fields](https://intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/mrl/1994/0001/%E2%80%A6) that for a number field $F$ and $m \geq 1$, the image of
$$\co_{2m-1}(\GL_{m-1}(F);\mathbb{Q}) \rightarrow \co_{2m-1}(\GL(F); \mathbb{Q})$$
misses the "primitive elements" in the Hopf algebra sense, which can be identified with $\ko_{2m-1}(F) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}$ by the Milnor–Moore structure theorem and the definition of (Quillen's) algebraic K-theory. This latter group is always nonzero by Borel's work, hence for odd $j$ we have $\mathbf{N}(F,j) \geq \frac{j+1}{2}$.

What else is known? Are there general lower bounds for countably infinite fields?

Comment: (1) is not correct, the range depends on the Bass stable range.

Comment: @skupers: This is all for fields.

Comment: @OscarRandal-Williams Ah, you are of course correct. One further data: a lower bound for number fields can be deduced from Borel-Yang, https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/mrl/1994/0001/0006/MRL-1994-0001-0006-a006.pdf.

Answer (score 4):

Some further data points:

(2') For a finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^r}$ with $p^r \neq 2$ one has $\mathbf{N}(\mathbb{F}_{p^r}, j) \leq \max(\lceil\tfrac{j}{2}\rceil, j-r(p-1)+3)$.

This is by combining Theorem A of Galatius--Kupers--R-W [$E_\infty$-cells and general linear groups of finite fields](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.11931) with Quillen's calculation of the $\mathbb{F}_\ell$-homology of $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_{p^r})$.

(3') $\mathbf{N}(\mathbb{F}_{2}, j) \leq \lceil\tfrac{3j+4}{2}\rceil$.

This is by combining Theorem B of the above paper with Quillen's calculation.